# Using POST with angularjs to send information

Tags: angularjs, post, controller

I am trying to retrieve information from a form and send it to a url however my method doesn't seem to be working.

```
insert: function(id, callback) {
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: listofIds/id,
                        data: {
                            single_id : id
                        }
                    }).success(callback);
                }
```

and then in a separate .js file

```
.controller('IDkeyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.update = function(newEntry) {
        console.log($scopeIDkey);
        $scope.id = $scope.IDkey;
    };

insert($scope.id);
```

I can tell that I'm calling the function insert() incorrectly here. Can someone help determine a better way to do it?

Comment: `insert` is in a factory? you need to inject that. As well need to pass the callback() function or it will no nothing with the data. Tell me if its a service, factory or provider and i will make a example code

Comment: @nada It is in a factory so in a separate file I have 

.factory('items, function($http) {

return {

insert : ... 

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Try with that:

```
.controller('IDkeyCtrl', ['$scope', 'yourFactory', function($scope, yourFactory) {

    $scope.update = function(newEntry) {
        console.log($scopeIDkey);
        $scope.id = $scope.IDkey;
    };

    $scope.functionOnClick = function() {
        yourFactory.insert($scope.id, function(response) {
            //do something with response data
        });
    }

}])

.factory('yourFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    return {
        insert: function(id, callback) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: listofIds/id,
                data: {
                    single_id : id
                }
            }).success(function(response) {
                callback(response)
            });
        }
    };

}]);

<button ng-click="functionOnClick()">Your Button</button
```

Comment: This seems to work however can I make it so that yourFactory.insert() is called when a button is clicked? 

Something like: 
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success" ng-click="yourFactory.insert($scope.id)">Find ID</button>

Comment: Hmm, using $scope.functionOnClick() that way gives me an error saying unnecessary {.

Comment: sorry i did a mistake :D look it now